# qmlRegisterType template fails if used in macro

Tags: c++, qt, qml, c-preprocessor

I'm currently working with Qt and qml files; many of the qml sources that I'm using takes advantage of the hability to publish C++ classes into the qml runtime with the `qmlRegisterType` template:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication application(argc,args);

    qmlRegisterType<Component1>("CompanyName", 1, 0, "Component1");
    qmlRegisterType<Component2>("CompanyName", 1, 0, "Component2");
    ...
    lots of components
    ...
    qmlRegisterType<ComponentN>("CompanyName", 1, 0, "ComponentN");

    return application.exec();
}
```

The amount of C++ types registered on qml is pretty high, and the registering is kind of cumbersome so I've decided to put the registering into a macro due to the fact that many of the data is repeated on all the registering process, the macro looks like the following:

```
#define QMLTYPE(T) qmlRegisterType<T>("CompanyName", 1, 0, #T);
```

And you can guess how is it intended to be used:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication application(argc,args);

    QMLTYPE(Component1);
    QMLTYPE(Component2);
    ...
    lots of components
    ...
    QMLTYPE(ComponentN);

    return application.exec();
}
```

AFAIK after expanding this macro the code should look like the first posted on this question so, the functionality should remain unaltered. But after launching the macro-version of the program, an error shows up:

> Component1 is not a type

It seems that the qml runtime is unable to found the types registered, as if the macro is failing or preventing the Qt voodoo to publish the type. Reverting to the no-macro-version the application runs without errors. I swear that the only difference between both versions is the use of a macro to call the `qmlRegisterType` template function.

After the explanation of the problem, let me ask a pair of questions:

- Is the `QMLTYPE(T)` macro correct or I made some kind of mistake typing that macro.
- If the macro isn't the problem and it expands to the expected code, is the Qt runtime unable to register the type because the macro "*doesn't look like a type registering*"?

I'm using Qt Creator (3.1.2) Based on Qt 5.3.1 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit)

Comment: last parameter  of qmlRegisterType is a string.

Comment: @UmNyobe I know, and a string is what it is receiving AFAIK ([stringification in macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html)).

Comment: The macro looks fine, invoke your compiler with the -E switch to see what the macro is expanded to. A trick is to pick the compile line from the Makefile, remove the "-o <file>" switch and replace "-c" with "-E".

Comment: Oh this is with msvc, have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xkfswhy.aspx but this should be similar.

Comment: @jturcotte I'm guessing if the "Qt preprocessor" and all the trickery that Qt does is performed BEFORE the macro expansion and thus, Qt is unable to detect that a type is expected to be registered.

Comment: The Qt preprocessor (moc) parses cpp files but has no effect on them, it generates a separate cpp file beside it containing the extra introspection and call table logic. Slots and signals are normal declared-only methods from the point of view of your own source code. It should not be involed in your issue.

Comment: @jturcotte so how is working Qt with the Qt keywords like `signal`, `slot`, `foreach`, ...? I always thought that the Qt preprocessor does a first pass to the source in order to change all the stuff that isn't from C++ but from Qt into real C++ code before pass it to the normal compilation engine.

Comment: Have a look at the "Magic Macros" section of http://woboq.com/blog/how-qt-signals-slots-work.html . The keywords are basically only there for moc to find them, when compiling your code normally most of those keywords are removed by the preprocessor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks of giving up on the problem, I’ve found what went wrong.

The macro is correct, and the code that uses the macro is correct too.

The problem is the capitalization of `Component1` which is used on the qml files with the name `component1` (first letter lowercase).

So the macro is publishing the type `Component1` while the code is using the type `component1`... it is a silly problem.